# Problems with decompressing messages in zlib

Tags: c, linux, zlib, compression

I have the following problem. I need to decompress the linux kernel messages generated from here: https://lkml.org/lkml/2014/3/17/525

The compression of messages in kernel looks following:

```
static int __init qr_compr_init(void)
{
    size_t size = max(zlib_deflate_workspacesize(MAX_WBITS, MAX_MEM_LEVEL),
            zlib_inflate_workspacesize());  
    stream.workspace = vmalloc(size);
    if (!stream.workspace)
        return -ENOMEM;
    return 0;
}

static void qr_compr_exit(void)
{
    vfree(stream.workspace);
}

static int qr_compress(void *in, void *out, size_t inlen, size_t outlen)
{
    int err, ret;
    int i;
    z_stream infstream;

ret = -EIO;

err = qr_compr_init();
if (err != 0)
    goto error;
mutex_lock(&compr_mutex);
err = zlib_deflateInit(&stream, COMPR_LEVEL);
if (err != Z_OK)
    goto error;

stream.avail_in = inlen;
stream.total_in = 0;
stream.next_out = out;
stream.avail_out = outlen;
stream.total_out = 0;

err = zlib_deflate(&stream, Z_FINISH);
if (err != Z_STREAM_END)
    goto error;

err = zlib_deflateEnd(&stream);
if (err != Z_OK)
    goto error;

if (stream.total_out >= stream.total_in)
    goto error;

ret = stream.total_out;

error:
    mutex_unlock(&compr_mutex);
    return ret;
}
```

It uses the zlib library from kernel.

My code for decompressing is following:

```
void uncompress_init()
{
    stream.zalloc = Z_NULL;
    stream.zfree = Z_NULL;
    stream.opaque = Z_NULL;
    stream.next_in = NULL;
    stream.avail_in = 0;
}

int uncompress_block(void *dst, int dstlen, void *src, int srclen)
{
    int err;

    stream.next_in = src;
    stream.avail_in = srclen;

    stream.next_out = dst;
    stream.avail_out = dstlen;

    inflateInit(&stream);

    err = inflate(&stream, Z_FINISH);
    if (err != Z_STREAM_END)
        goto err;
    return stream.total_out;

err:
    printf("Error %d while decompressing!\n", err);
    printf("%p(%d)->%p(%d)\n", src, srclen, dst, dstlen);
    return -1;
}

void uncompress_exit()
{
    inflateEnd(&stream);
}
```

Unofrtunately it doesn't work. I got following error message:

```
compressed string size: 8
compressed string: x廳L#
Error -3 while decompressing!
0x7ffe9be69f68(8)->0x7ffe9be6a360(1024)
Uncompressed size is: 0
Uncompressed string is:
```

I found this decompression example in kernel code.
I would very appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

The -3 is a data error, indicating invalid zlib or deflate input was provided to inflate.  Therefore, what you are feeding inflate is not what came out of deflate.  Somewhere along the line the data is either being corrupted or misidentified.